# Sum duplicate rows with a date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet that has four columns as seen in the image below.

[image]

How can I combine the duplicated AssetNames so that the dates don't get summed but the Active and Active count columns do? I tried consolidating but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Post data as text table instead of screenshot. We can not copy your data for further work. Also what would be your output in this case and what is logic to gain that output?

Comment: What do you want to happen with the dates?  In other words, what would your output look like (edit your question to show a screenshot of desired output).

Answer (score 0):

I would use Pivot table where your rows are AssetName and values are Active and Active count.
You get something like this: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GhI2.png)